# What am I? Series 1.1

Tags: riddle, letters

I'm a letter.

I am found in an elephant and oh! I am heard too, by a person sense of hearing!

Sometimes, I am also used in a cartesian plane, or maybe used as a word to describe things are growing really.. really fast.. unless I am negative :/.

I am a letter, but found commonly in letters! And I am also sometimes commonly known as a latter (In English).

Beat that! I'm inbetween the lines of music that have a very troubled chef.... just below the highest "seen" staff. Look at that buns I just made! (I know it's bad)

I'm used in banks after I was discovered by approaching to a limit. I mean, I was discovered to have numeric use.

A child uses me when in digust (sometimes).

Oh... I'm so rational... NOT.

So... what am I? (I also like to see how you explain the paragraphs that I written. The difficulty is just why that letter represents some of the paragraphs. Not the guessing :/.)

Clue 1 (Beat that!....just made!):

> Change a "b" to a "p" in that paragraph and you notice the paragraph is.. literally... sigh.

Clue 2 (And...English)

> Vowels. But even if you explain all the paragraph correct except for this, I would accept your full explanation answer because that sentence is ambiguous. Sorry. "vowels" is what I have in my mind.

Clue 3 (I'm used in banks... numeric use):

> How do you think I was mathematically discovered. I mean, English already created me but it took a while before mathematics discovered me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> e

I'm a letter.

> E is a letter

I am found in an elephant

> E is in the word elephant

and oh! I am heard too, by a person sense of hearing!

> **e**ar

Sometimes, I am also used in a cartesian plane, or maybe used as a word to describe things are growing really.. really fast.. unless I am negative :/.

> **E**uclidean plane (thanks to @Dalton) and **E**xponential, also e^x?

I am a letter, but found commonly in letters!

> E is the most commonly used letter in the English language

And I am also sometimes commonly known as a latter (In English).

> **e**nd

Beat that! I'm in between the lines of music that have a very troubled chef.... just below the highest "seen" staff. Look at that buns I just made! (I know it's bad)

> e is the highest note inside the staff on treble clef (pun time!!)

I'm used in banks after I was discovered by approaching to a limit. I mean, I was discovered to have numeric use.

> Honestly still stumped by this one

A child uses me when in digust (sometimes).

> **e**w?

Oh... I'm so rational... NOT.

> e, as in euler's number, is irrational

Comment: Most of them are correct. The "Beat that!... staff" is partiall right, partially wrong. The "Look at that buns I just made (I know it's bad) is linked. "A child uses me when in digust" is also almost correct.

Comment: I'll finish it up after lunch

Comment: Moose, re banks: it's about compound interest, the limit being as you compound over shorter and shorter terms.

Comment: @ministic2001 does r have something to do with hot cross buns?

Comment: Nope. Your explanation is actually correct but that one word just E-rritate me and kind of make the explanation wrong XD (Yes, "E-rritate" is kind of a clue I guess.)

Comment: Changed 1 word to make it more obvious. I just notice the "some" in "troublesome" just makes it very ambiguous. Sorry.

Comment: Music: the space just inside the top of the treble clef is E. A lower-pitch E is in the central space of the bass clef, but the high E fits the wording better.

Comment: Notice: Nothing to do with an egg. "Troubled Chef" "Treble Clef".

Answer (score 2):

You are

> the letter 'e'

I am found in an elephant and oh! I am heard too, by a person sense of hearing!

> **e**l**e**phant, **e**ar

Sometimes, I am also used in a cartesian plane,

> **E**uclidean space

or maybe used as a word to describe things are growing really.. really fast.. unless I am negative :/.

> growing really fast - **e**xponentially

I am a letter, but found commonly in letters!

> l**e**tt**e**r

And I am also sometimes commonly known as a latter (In English).

> **e**nd

Beat that! I'm inbetween the lines of music that have a very troublesome chef....

> **e**ggs as in beat the eggs when cooking (chef)

just below the highest "seen" staff. Look at that buns I just made! (I know it's bad)

> e on a musical scale is the highest note and falls between staff lines

I'm used in banks

> **e**uro

after I was discovered by approaching to a limit.

> **e**stimate

I mean, I was discovered to have numeric use.

> Euler's number (represented as **e** in mathematics)

A child uses me when in digust (sometimes).

> **e**ww maybe?

Oh... I'm so rational... NOT.

> Euler's number is irrational

Comment: Well done! Initially, I thought "e" means exponential in mathematics taught but my teacher but oh well. Its.. just a letter that doesn't mean to represent anything. Though, "A child uses me when in digust is kind of not correct. But really close.

Comment: But this doesnt explain everything. "And I am also sometimes commonly known as a latter" "That have a very troublesome chef... buns I just made" (The phrase inbetween buns and chef is correct.) 'I was disovered by approaching a limit" "i'm used in banks"

Comment: Beatcha by 2 minutes :P

Comment: Am I getting anywhere? haha

Comment: "And I am also sometimes commonly... English)" is wrong. But since it's ambiguous, then I guess no need to explain that. Will give clues to what I was actually thinking

Comment: And no, it is not eggs or cookin related. Its under music and is related to the "highest 'seen' staff". "I'm used.... limit" is wrong.

Comment: I'm used in banks" "After I.. limit" is wrong. It have nothing to do with the starting letter "e"

Answer (score 2):

You are an

> e

I am found in elephant

> **e**lephant

I am heard too, by a person sense of hearing

> **e**ar

Sometimes, I am also used in a cartesian plane, or maybe used as a word to describe things are growing really.. really fast.. unless I am negative :/.

> "e" can describe exponentially, which graphically, represent on a cartesian plane with the equation y=$e^x$ but if you are $y$=$-e^x$, you instead fall (That's why "Unless I am Negative")

I am a letter, but found commonly in letters! And I am also sometimes commonly known as a latter (In English).

> Well, you do see the letter "e" in letters or electronic-mail. "e" is a latter in English vowel because "e" is the second vowel.

Beat that! I'm inbetween the lines of music that have a very troubled chef.... just below the highest "seen" staff. Look at that buns I just made! (I know it's bad)

> "Beat" is a musical reference showing that the paragraph is related to music. The note "e" is found in between the highest and the second highest staff (Inbetween the lines of music. Just below the highest "seen" staff) when it is treble clef (Troubled Chef). Of course, the paragraph tries to show that the paragraph is a pun ("buns") and it is bad.

I'm used in banks after I was discovered by approaching to a limit. I mean, I was discovered to have numeric use.

> "e" is a mathematical constant found by someone by noticing that when "n" goes really large with the expression $(1 + \frac {1} {n})^n$. "e" is commonly used in compound interest.Though, "e" is known in English already (And other languages) therefore "I mean, I was discovered to have numeric use"

A child uses me when in disgust (sometimes).

> Depending on which country you are, I'm sure you meant "eeeeeeee" as a sign of disgust.

Oh... I'm so rational... NOT.

> "e" is irrational.